# upgrade my PHP version from 5.2.3 to 5.5.9

Tags: php

I want to upgrade my PHP version from 5.2.3  to 5.5.9. I want to know what are the major problems involved with the functionality after upgradation . 
My PHP is running in WAMP server.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Check the [changelogs](http://php.net/ChangeLog-5.php#5.5.9) for deprecated functions, as they're the most likely to start triggering warnings and notices

Comment: Thanx Mark... But actually i need to prepare a documentation which includes basically the common faults that may arises after upgradation.

Comment: It's all documented: http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.php (and previous versions...)

Comment: 5.2.3 was released 8 years ago, and why 5.5.9?  The current stable 5.5 is 5.5.24.  You really need to keep track of updates better, so many security fixes have been addressed since then and PHP 5.2 has been EOL for several years.

Comment: Check out PHPCS. They have migration sniffs between versions.

Comment: Yeah Devon.. But my requirement is to upgrade an application that is already developed in php 5.2.3 to php 5.5.9 only ... Thats why i want to know whether that application will work exactly the way it works in php 5.2.3 ??

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is that yes, your code *could* break so you should test it.

Here's the list of [Backward Incompatible Changes](http://php.net/manual/en/migration53.incompatible.php) from PHP 5.2 to 5.3

And here's the list of [Backward Incompatible Changes](http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.incompatible.php) from PHP 5.3 to 5.4

And here's the list of [Backward Incompatible Changes](http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.incompatible.php) from PHP 5.4 to 5.5

Read each of these and see if you're using any of those functions in the ways described.